# Reading large txt efficiently in c++

Tags: c++, boost, large-files

I have to read a large text file (> 10 GB) in C++. This is a csv file with variable length lines. when I try to read line by line using ifstream it works but takes long time, i guess this is becuase each time I read a line it goes to disk and reads, which makes it very slow.

Is there a way to read in bufferes, for example read 250 MB at one shot (using read method of ifstream) and then get lines from this buffer, i see lot of issues with solution like buffer can have incomplete lines etc..

Is there a solution for this in c++ which handles all these cases etc. Are there any open source libraries that can do this for example boost etc ?

Note: I would want to avoid c stye FILE* pointers etc.

Comment: The standard library already uses buffers. It takes a long time because the file is big. Maybe you are doing something else. Post the code you use we can comment on that.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the Windows memory mapped file function.  The calls are buffered and you get to treat a file as if its just memory.
[memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Unless the environment is 64b, it will be impossible to map whole 10 GB file into one view, therefore even with this approach line boundaries need to be handled the same way as with buffers. That said, relying on OS to handle all the I/O and buffering using memory mapped files is still interesting and gives great performance.

Answer (score 3):

IOstreams already use buffers much as you describe (though usually only a few kilobytes, not hundreds of megabytes). You can use `pubsetbuf` to get it to use a larger buffer, but I wouldn't expect any huge gains. Most of the overhead in IOstreams stems from other areas (like using virtual functions), not from lack of buffering.

If you're running this on Windows, you might be able to gain a little by writing your own stream buffer, and having it call `CreateFile` directly, passing (for example) `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` or `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. Under the circumstances, either of these may help your performance substantially.

Answer (score 3):

If you want real speed, then you're going to have to stop reading lines into std::string, and start using `char*`s into the buffer.  Whether you read that buffer using `ifstream::read()` or memory mapped files is less important, though read() has the disadvantage you note about potentially having N complete lines and an incomplete one in the buffer, and needing to recognise that (can easily do that by scanning the rest of the buffer for '\n' - perhaps by putting a NUL after the buffer and using `strchr`).  You'll also need to copy the partial line to the start of the buffer, read the next chunk from file so it continues from that point, and change the maximum number of characters read such that it doesn't overflow the buffer.  If you're nervous about FILE*, I hope you're comfortable with const char*....

As you're proposing this for performance reasons, I do hope you've profiled to make sure that it's not your CSV field extraction etc. that's the real bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps -

http://www.cppprog.com/boost_doc/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file

BTW, you wrote "i see lot of issues with solution like buffer can have incomplete lines etc.." - in this situation how about reading 250 MB and then read char by char until you get the delimiter to complete the line.